# Reduce repetition in these Redux CRUD actions

Tags: generics, typescript, redux, axios

My React application manages some entities. I'm using Redux (with redux-thunk) to manage the application state. I've created a RESTClient based on Axios:

```
export class RESTClient<E extends { id: number }> extends Client {
  protected path: string;
  public constructor(path: string, token?: string) {
    super(token);
    this.path = path;
  }

  public index() {
    return this.clientInstance.get<E[]>(this.path);
  }

  public create(entity: Omit<E, 'id'>) {
    return this.clientInstance.post<E>(this.path, entity);
  }

  public update(entity: E) {
    return this.clientInstance.put<E>(`${this.path}/${entity.id}`, entity);
  }

  public delete(entity: E) {
    return this.clientInstance.delete<E>(`${this.path}/${entity.id}`);
  }
}
```

This RESTClient is used by a Redux action generator:

```
export const createClientAction = <T extends Client>(
  type: new (token?: string) => T,
  action: (client: T, dispatch: Dispatch, getState: () => State) => void
) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: () => State) => {
    const clientInstance = getState().session.isAuthenticated ? new type(getState().session.token) : new type();
    action(clientInstance, dispatch, getState);
  };
};
```

Now to create a delete action for the entity participant I create an action as follows:

```
import { createAction } from 'typesafe-actions';

const deleteParticipantSuccess = createAction('participant/DELETE', (participant: Participant) => participant)();

export const deleteParticipant = (participant: Participant) => {
  return createClientAction(ParticipantClient, (client, dispatch) => {
    client.delete(participant).then(() => {
      dispatch(deleteParticipantSuccess(participant));
      dispatch(
        addEvent({
          message: 'event.success.deleted',
          values: { entity: participant.email },
          type: EventType.SUCCESS
        })
      );
    });
  });
};
```

Obviously for error handling I need to add a few lines.

When I implement all CRUD-Actions with error handling I have per entity ~150 lines of code. What would you do with this, to DRY it up?

1. Would you write something which generates the CRUD actions?
2. Do you think I would benefit if I use sagas instead of redux-think?
3. Do you think I could simplify things if I implement a custom Redux middleware, especially regarding to the event dispatches?

Comment: Is `createAction` defined in one of the libraries you use, or custom? If custom, can you add the code of `createAction`?

Comment: `createAction` is from `typesafe-actions`: https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions